# Cmake include files

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, gpio

Now I'm working on my school project using raspberry pi. It is my first experience with raspberry and terminal programming too. For my project I use c++. I already made couple of things and now I'm on a finish line. The only thing I need to do just toggle one of pins of raspberry. I found a library for it, but there are no special files to find it using cmake (I used it with two more libraries used in my project before). And now I completely stacked. I spend a lot of time trying investigate how could I make it work, but it is way too complicated for my nooby skills. Could somebody give me a small step by step tutorial how could I make it. I have my project project.c and also I have in the same folder two files file.h and file.c (file.c including everything I need to control GPIO) In my project.c I have file.h included. Could you tell me what should I write in my CMakeLists.txt to link to this library (Please could you be as simpler as possible during explanation).

I'm trying to compile [this library](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15). Basically I created three fails: RPI.h RPI.c and main.c (and copied code from tutorial) All of them are in one directory. In main.c I'm including RPI.h to get functionality of RPI.c. And now I would like to compile it with cmake. That is basically what I made. I tried to create a CMakeLists.txt by my own, but haven't succeed.

Comment: You don't even mention what the library is, or what form you're trying to use it in. Is it source code you have to compile, dlls, libs, dylibs, .a archives, .so files? Those details are necessary to answer your question.

Comment: I'm trying to compile this library http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15. Basically I created three fails: RPI.h RPI.c and main.c (and copied code from tutorial) All of them are in one directory. In main.c I'm including RPI.h to get functionality of RPI.c. And now I would like to compile it with cmake. That is basically what I made. I tried to create a CMakeLists.txt by my own, but haven't succeed. :/ Sorry, next time I'll try to be more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page links to a repository containing the files and a CMakeLists.txt file that shows how to build the library.

You can build the library and link to it by putting the following in your own CMakeLists.txt that you have building your project.

```
add_library(PJ_RPI PJ_RPI.c)

target_link_libraries(your_project_target PRIVATE PJ_RPI)
```

You'll need to replace `your_project_target` in the above with whatever you named your main executable target. (i.e., in your `add_executable(... main.c)` command)

Alternatively you could just add PG_RPI.c directly as another source in your main executable target: `add_executable(... main.c PJ_RPI.c)`